# How to put the finite difference in a a matrix to solve the linear system

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-differences

After doing the finite difference approximation of a pde equation or ode, we have a linear equation of the fnite difference . how do we put this equation into a matrix to solve it? I want the actual steps of putting the numbers in the rows of the matrix because i don't find anything explains this!! How do we put the coefficients in the matrix? Is it like the usual linear equations? I how does the linear system become sparse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of your questions of course depends on the problem you are discretising and the particular finite difference stencil you use, however I'll try to illustrate with an example:

Say that we want to solve the ODE
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt} + \lambda u &= 0, \quad 0 < t \leq 1 \\
u &= f, \quad t=0.
\end{align}
We divide time into $N$ intervals of length $\Delta t$ and denote the numerical solution at time step $j$ as $v^j$. In other words, time is now discretised into points $t_j$, $j=0, \dots, N$ and the numerical solution is $v^j \approx u(t_j)$.

Say that we want to approximate the time derivative using a second order accurate central stencil:
$$
\frac{du}{dt} \Big|_{t=t_j} \approx \frac{v_{j+1} - v_{j-1}}{2 \Delta t}.
$$
Thus, we replace the ODE above with the $N-1$ equations
$$
\frac{v_{j+1} - v_{j-1}}{2 \Delta t} + \lambda v_j = 0, \quad j=1, \dots N-1.
$$
I have excluded $j=0$ and $j=N$ here because the central stencil cannot be applied at these points. Nonetheless, we now have a set of linear equations involving the unknowns $v_j$ and $v_{j \pm 1}$. On matrix form this becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\ddots & & & & & & \\
& \ddots & & & & & \\
& -\frac{1}{2\Delta t} & \lambda & \frac{1}{2\Delta t} & & & \\
& & -\frac{1}{2\Delta t} & \lambda & \frac{1}{2\Delta t} & & \\
& & & -\frac{1}{2\Delta t} & \lambda & \frac{1}{2\Delta t} & \\
& & & & & \ddots & \\
& & & & & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
\vdots \\
v_{j-2} \\
v_{j-1} \\
v_j \\
v_{j+1} \\
v_{j+2} \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\vdots \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The general procedure here is that everything that multiplies $v_j$ (in this case $\lambda$) ends up on the diagonal, everything that multiplies $v_{j-1}$ ends up on the first sub-diagonal and everything that multiplies $v_{j+1}$ ends up on the first super-diagonal. Everything else is zero, hence the matrix is sparse. The number of rows of the matrix corresponds to the number of points in the discretisation, in this case $N+1$. Of course, the stencil would have to be modified on the first and last rows since the central stencil simple does not fit.

Comment: Thanks! So what happens after this? We have a large set of equations so how to solve this linear system we have different unknowns in every equation.

Comment: Well, solving sets of linear equations is something computers are very good at so the matrix and the vector on the right-hand side is typically typed into your favourite numerical solver (e.g. Matlab) which handles the rest. Solving linear systems is an entire science on its own and cannot be covered adequately here, but if you want to know more you can start by searching for "LU factorisation" or "Gaussian elimination" and work your way from there.

Comment: Here will we solve for u+1 and u and u-1? Or only u???

Comment: In the example above $u$ is the solution of the continuous problem, which we don't solve. Instead, we solve the discretised problem, where the variable is $v$. As for linear systems in general, we solve for all components of $v$ simultaneously.

Comment: I am trying to understand conjugate gradient method in a simple way but I don't find anything that I can understand

Comment: Must we add boundary conditions or we can solve without them?

Comment: Yes, boundary conditions should be added, otherwise we are not approximating the continuous problem properly. Also, the matrix is not invertible without some form of boundary treatment.

Comment: With the gauss seidel we don't have to add boundary conditions. Also I saw codes of fluid simulations like jos stam's code he doesn't work the boundaries like math.

Comment: Be careful not to mix the questions. Gauss Seidel is a method used to solve the linear system. It has nothing to do with the approximation of the continuous problem. If the problem you want to solve has a boundary condition then so should the discretisation.

Comment: Can i post the code for you to see it?

Comment: If you have a link to the code you could post it in a comment.

Comment: https://www.autodeskresearch.com/sites/default/files/TheArtOfFluidAnimationCode.zip