# Deriving the linear system for a fnite difference approximation of a boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

Consider the boundary value problem $$u^{''} (x) + u'(x) =f(x), \quad  0 \le x \le 1$$
with $u(0) = u_\alpha$ and $u(1) = u_\beta.$

The goal is to derive the linear system for a finite difference approximation of $u(x)$ at points $x_0 = 0, \ldots, x_{n+1} = 1.$

After reading a similar post from here [How to put the finite difference in a a matrix to solve the linear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2245519), I manage to write out the linear system for the above problem and I am seeking proofreading, addition and subtraction of the following:

The three mesh are:
\begin{align*}
x_0 & = u_\alpha, \\ 
x_1 & = \frac{u_\alpha + u_\beta}{n} \\
x_2 & = u_\beta 
\end{align*}
From boundary conditions, we get

$y_0 = u(x_0 = 0) = u_\alpha$ and

$y_{n+1} = u(x_{n+1 } = 1) = u_\beta.$

`We then seek to approximate` $y_1 \approx u(x_1), \ldots, y_n \approx u(x_n)$

\begin{align}
u''(x_i) + u'(x_i) & \approx \frac{y_{i+1} - 2y_i + y_{i-1}}{h^2} + \frac{y_{i+1} - y_i }{2h} = f(x_i)\\ \\
u''(x_1) + u'(x_1) & \approx \frac{y_{2} - 2y_1 + y_{0}}{h^2} + \frac{y_{2} - y_1 }{2h} = 
\frac{(2+h)y_2 - 4y_1 + (2-h)y_0}{2h^2} = f(x_1)\\\\
u''(x_2) + u'(x_2) & \approx \frac{y_{3} - 2y_2 + y_{1}}{h^2} + \frac{y_{3} - y_2 }{2h} = \frac{(2+h)y_3 - 4y_2 + (2-h)y_1}{2h^2} = f(x_2)\\\\
\vdots & \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \vdots\\\\
u''(x_n) + u'(x_n) & \approx \frac{y_{n+1} - 2y_n + y_{n-1}}{h^2} + \frac{y_{n+1} - y_{n-1} }{2h} = \frac{(2+h)y_{n+1} - 4y_n + (2-h)y_{n-1}}{2h^2} = f(x_n)
\end{align}
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & & & & \\
(2-h) & -4 & (h+2) & & &\\
0 & (2-h) & -4 & (h+2) &\\
0 & 0 & (2-h) & -4 & (h+2)&\\ 
& \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\\ & & & \ddots(2-h) & -4 & (h+2\\
& & & & & \\ 
& & & & & & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0 \\ y_1 \\y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_\alpha \\  \\ 2h^2f(x_1) \\ \\ 2h^2f(x_2) \\\\ \vdots \\ u_\beta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I think there's a formatting problem with the text. Can anyone help to rectify the issue for clear visibility?

Comment: You have some (sign) differences in what DE you actually solve, and you probably wanted the central difference quotient for the first derivative in all places.

Comment: The sign is positive on the RHS not negative, I've corrected it. Is my work now correct?

Comment: The problem with the first derivative persists. The conclusion is correct, so you have a double error that cancels.